# Querying two tables with shared variables SQL

Tags: sql, join

I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around how I would accomplish this in SQL.

There are two tables
One is called "Job":

Fields:

```
ObjectID
Job_Number
```

the other is called "Job_Operation".

Fields:

```
ObjectID
Work_Center
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out the Work_Center when given the Job_Number by going through the ObjectID which should be shared between them. It seems like this should be fairly straightforward but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around joins. What is the best way to tackle this with a single query?

I have tried

```
SELECT Work_Center FROM Job, Job_Operation
WHERE Job.ObjectID = Job_Operation.ObjectID AND Job.Job_Number = '34412'
```

This did not return anything which I'm certain it would have if my query was structured correctly.

Comment: Please share here what you have tried and where you struggled.

Comment: Please: Ask 1 specific reserarched non-duplicate question. Clarify via edits, not comments. In code questions give a [mre]. On an error drop your overall goal & find the 1st expression with a result you don't expect & say what you expected & why.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a simple `join`?

```
select j.*, jo.work_center
from job j
inner join job_operation jo on jo.object_id = j.object_id
```

Comment: I am confused where all of the j. and jo. came from in your query. Can you explain?

Comment: @JustinTime: these are table aliases for the original tables. `j` stands for `jobs`, and `jo` for `job_operation`.

Comment: thank you. This actually helped a lot. I was able to get it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT J.ObjectID,J.Job_Number,JO.Work_Center
FROM JOB J
JOIN Job_Operation JO ON J.objectID = JO.objectID
WHERE J.Job_Number = @Jobnumber
```

Comment: Thank you! How would this be modified to narrow the results to a single job given the Job_Number.  As it is this would return every job with a work_center assigned to it. The goal is to feed in the job_number and have the work_center(s) name(s) returned. Once I understand how that works I think I'll be able to take it from there.

Comment: Check my edited answer. You need to pass you job number to @jobnumber